# JWPlayer not playing Wowza streams over rtmp through smil paylist

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, wowza, smil, jwplayer7

I'm trying to load a rtmp audio stream from a Wowza server into JWPlayer 7.  The stream works fine if I load it in directly into JWPlayer.
But I want to load it from a Smil file (the reason for this is I can create the smil files on-demand, which I need to do because I want generate url signatures for the stream at the time that the user decides to press play).

When I try to load my Smil file into JWPlayer, I get the following errors when I hit play:

`Error loading stream: Could not connect to server`

I can see that it loads the smil file (from my Chrome network) tab.

Here are the contents of my smil file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language" >
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://media.myserver.com:80/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
        <video src="secureaudios3/local_inst?expires=1467199671&signature=xxx&filename=mp4%3Aamazons3%2Fstorage-bucket-dev%2Ftracks%2Ftrackname.m4a&fid=8388&user=0&dummy=/mp4:amazons3/storage-bucket-dev/tracks/trackname.m4a" />
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

The rtmp url works fine (I can play this if I load is a source directly in JWPlayer, and also through VLC).  It just won't play when loaded through the Smil file.

Here is my JWPlayer setup object:

```js
{
  "width": "411",
  "height": "63",
  "stretching": "fill",
  "primary": "flash",
  "autostart": 0,
  "repeat": false,
  "rtmp": {
    "bufferlength": 0.1
  },
  "playlist": [
    {
      "sources": [
        {
          "default": false,
          "file": "http://www.example.com/path/to/playlist.smil",
          "type": "rtmp",
          "label": "0",
          "androidhls": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "controls": 1,
  "androidhls": 1,
  "debug": true,
  "events": {},
  "id": "jwplayer_93e629982991a71e69a3f90750980c3d"
}
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can I see your JWPlayer setup? how do you add the smile file into the conf?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: have you tried using the audioonly parameter? It should look similar to:
        <video src="secureaudios3/local_inst?expires=1467199671&signature=xxx&filename=mp4%3Aamazons3%2Fstorage-bucket-dev%2Ftracks%2Ftrackname.m4a&fid=8388&user=0&dummy=/mp4:amazons3/storage-bucket-dev/tracks/trackname.m4a">
     <param name="audioOnly" value="TRUE" valuetype="data"/>
</video>